# AndEngine: How do I change the color of a texture BEFORE it is part of an Entity

Tags: android, image-processing, colors, andengine

Using a class called LayeredAssetsBitmapTextureAtlasSource (which you can look at here:http://pastebin.com/vgfT1U5j) I am currently stacking multiple png images comprised of character pieces into one atlas and making a character sprite from parts.  I have my sprite sheets for those parts done where everything except that part (pants, for example) is transparent.  I have made multiple differently colored spritesheets for all the parts of the character: pants, shoes, shirt, gloves, head, hat, sword.  LayeredAssetsBitmapTextureAtlasSource lets me sandwich them together into the same atlas, and make one AnimatedSprite from it.

I update the colors of the character's costume as new items are found by recreating the process.

What I'd like to do now is to programmatically change the colors of those parts before they're put into the atlas, so that my item diversity can go way up, but I don't have to spend so much time in GIMP colorizing everything... also, having tons of color variations saved in PNG's greatly increases my apk size.  I would like to do the parts in white and colorize them on the fly.

I'm able to use Entity.setColor to colorize whole sprites, but I can't seem to find the overridden method that actually accomplishes this.  It looks like it just sets a color value that is utilized elsewhere.  So reverse engineering a solution from that has thus far been a fail.

I'm not sure shaders will work from what I've read, but I could be wrong.  I believe I need to make a copy of the image, and colorize it, and then use that copy in the atlas, but I don't know how to begin to do that.

Anyone got any ideas?  Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out....  The answer was to use Paint and ColorFilter on the Canvas in the LayeredAssetsBitmapTextureAtlasSource.

For the whole class file, look here http://pastebin.com/0wXUbLmk

For the pertinent changes, look below

@Override
   public Bitmap onLoadBitmap(final Config pBitmapConfig)
   {
      final Bitmap image = BitmapFromAsset(mContext, BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.getAssetBasePath() + this.mBaseAssetPath);//mBaseAssetPath);
      if (image == null)
         return null;

```
  final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mTextureWidth, mTextureHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0f, 0f, null);
  for (int i = 0; i < mAssetLayers.size(); i++)
  {
      Paint p = new Paint();
      int color =  Color.rgb(100,100,2);
      ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter(color, 0);
      p.setColorFilter(filter);


     final AssetLayer al = mAssetLayers.get(i);
     final Bitmap layer = BitmapFromAsset(mContext, BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.getAssetBasePath() + al.mAssetPath);
     canvas.drawBitmap(layer, al.mXOffset, al.mYOffset, p);
  }
  return bitmap;
```

}